# What are the failure cases of round(val * 10 ** ndigits) vs. round(val, ndigits) in python?

Tags: python, floating-point

Users of my software are complaining that in certain cases, there are obvious rounding errors (due to floating point representation issues):

```
>>> round(4.55, 1)
4.5
>>> '{:.60f}'.format(4.55)
'4.549999999999999822364316059974953532218933105468750000000000'
```

I am considering replacing the current rounding functionality with the following:

```
>>> def round_human(val, ndigits):
...     return round(val * 10 ** ndigits) / 10 ** ndigits
... 
>>> round_human(4.55, 1)
4.6
```

Or (the `repr` in there makes me uneasy, but as the numbers have already passed through `numpy` by this point, I'm not sure what better choice I have):

```
>>> def round_decimal(val, ndigits):
...     return float(Decimal(repr(val)).quantize(Decimal(10) ** -ndigits))
... 
>>> round_decimal(4.55, 1)
4.6
```

Are there cases where either of these functions produce rounded results that look wrong to human inspection? I'm not worried about cases where `ndigits` is more than 3 or so.

Is there a better approach in general?

Comment: Why are you using `round` at all?  Just print the number with the representation you want, don't round it.

Comment: It's difficult to say if there is a better approach without understanding more about your problem, or why you consider the original behaviour problematic.

Comment: @wim do you mean something like `'{:.1f}'.format(4.55) == '4.5'`? Because that's still incorrect.

@SimonByrne What's unclear about `round(4.55, 1) == 4.5` being incorrect to the human eye? My users don't care about IEEE floating point, they just think we're bad at math.

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.  It is not incorrect.  The float `float('4.55')` is closer to the number 4.5 than it is to the number 4.6.

Comment: What do these numbers represent? Should they have been stored and manipulated in decimal from the start?

Comment: @wim floats not being able to exactly represent 4.55 doesn't mean that rounding 4.55 to one decimal digit has a "right answer" of 4.5. If a 3rd grader put that on their math test, they'd get marked wrong. In my use case, IEEE floating point is an implementation detail, not a justification for incorrect behavior.

Comment: @user2357112 in this case, distances that a mechanical component has moved from the default rest position. `Decimal` storage at the top level has a couple of issue, largest being that there's no business justification for retrofitting the majority of a codebase that's got ~25 engineer-years of work put into it. Second, some of our numbers get spit out by CUDA, and even if there's a CUDA lib for arbitrary precision decimals out there, the performance hit isn't going to be worth it (esp. given there being a one-line function that seems to do the right thing). I swear this isn't an XY problem.

Comment: You keep talking about "incorrect behaviour" but you haven't said what is the incorrect behaviour.  Python parses the input `4.55` into a floating point number that is less that 4.55.  This has nothing to do with `round`, round behaves correctly.  Do you want `round` to behave incorrectly, and pick the further number?

Comment: @wim I have explained a couple of times now. I think you're losing sight of the idea of numbers that exist independently from their IEEE floating point representation. Yes, `round(4.55, 1) == 4.5` is expected behavior by anyone who knows how IEEE floating point works, but that doesn't make it correct, in the same way that `0.1+0.2 == 0.30000000000000004` isn't correct.

Comment: I'm distinguishing between `4.55` (a python literal) and 4.55 (a real number).  Perhaps you are not?  It's still not clear to me where exactly you think the incorrect behaviour is - when you write `round(4.55, 1)` the damage has already been done by python's parser and tokenizer, before `round` has even been called.  So if your data comes from some string somewhere, e.g. from user input or from text file, then you'll need to parse it into a better datatype at that time.  If, as you've mentioned, using some datatype other than floats is too impractical - then it's the users complaining ...

Comment: ... who need to be educated about how floats work.  You should not cripple your software to produce sub-optimal numbers just because some users don't understand floating point representation details.  I guess I'm echoing @SimonByrne earlier comment asking about "why you consider the original behaviour problematic".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized that I could write a test to brute-force all of the interesting cases. The odd print statements in the test below produce the `golden_dict`, which is then manually inspected for the desired behavior.

```
def test_rounding(self):
    print '        golden_dict = {'

    golden_dict = {
        ('1.005', 2): 1.01,
        ('1.015', 2): 1.02,
        # ...
        ('1.95', 1): 2.0,
    }

    try:
        for a, b, c in itertools.product(range(10), range(10), range(10)):
            s = '1.{}{}{}'.format(a, b, c).rstrip('0')
            self.assertEqual(s.lstrip('+'), repr(float(s)).rstrip('0'))

            for ndigits in [1, 2, 3]:
                q = decimal.Decimal('0.{}1'.format('0' * (ndigits-1)))
                g = golden_dict.get((s, ndigits), round(float(s), ndigits))

                rdp = show.round_decimal(float(s), ndigits)
                rdn = show.round_decimal(float('-' + s), ndigits)

                try:
                    self.assertEqual(rdp, -rdn)
                    self.assertEqual(rdp, g, \
                            "{}: {} != {}".format(s, rdp, g))
                except:
                    print '            ({!r:6}, {!r}): {!r},'\
                            .format(s, ndigits, rdp)
                    # Comment this raise out to produce the 
                    # entire golden_dict all at once.
                    raise

    finally:
        print '        }'
```

The function that worked best:

```
def round_decimal(val, places):
    s = repr(val)
    if places < 1:
        q = decimal.Decimal(10 ** -places)
    else:
        q = decimal.Decimal('0.{}1'.format('0' * (places-1)))
    f = float(decimal.Decimal(s).quantize(q, rounding=decimal.ROUND_HALF_UP))

    return f
```

This relies on python's magical `repr(4.55)` behavior, which is described here: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html and here https://bugs.python.org/issue1580 (this last one's a saga).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following function for rounding; it usually works better than `round()` itself:

```
def my_round(x):
    return int(x*10+(0.5 if x > 0 else -0.5))/10
```

Comment: I'm not particularly interested in alternate implementations unless there's a demonstrated weakness that is fixed by the suggestion. In this case, I need the function to work for negative numbers.

Comment: Okay.  Still doesn't answer my question, since I'm asking about weaknesses in my (and your) proposed solution. I'm looking for failure cases that would work for `round(x, 1)` but fail for these.